# In Laravel, how can I get *only* POST parameters?

Tags: php, laravel, http-post, laravel-request

I know that one can use `$request->get('my_param')` or `Input::get('my_param')` to get a POST or GET request parameter in Laravel (I'm toying with v5/dev version now, but it's the same for 4.2).

**But how can I make sure that my `my_param` came via a POST parameter and was not just from a `?my_param=42` appended to the URL?** (besides reverting to the ol' `$_POST` and `$_GET` superglobals and throwing testability out the window)

(Note: I also know that the `Request::get` method will give me the POST param for a POST request, if both a POST an URL/GET param with the same name exist, but... but if the param land in via the url query string instead, I want a Laravel-idiomatic way to know this)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the class `Illuminate\Http\Request` (or actually the Symphony class it extends from `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`) there are two class variables that store request parameters.

`public $query` - for GET parameters

`public $request` - for POST parameters

Both are an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag` which implements a `get` method.

Here's what you can do (although it's not very pretty)

```
$request = Request::instance();
$request->request->get('my_param');
```

Comment: Or you could use this syntax: 
`$request = Input::instance()->request->get('my_param');`

Same thing though, just sayin

Comment: $request->post() or Request::post()

Answer (score -4):

Why trying to complicate things when you can do easily what you need :

```
$posted = $_POST;
```

Comment: 1. Not good for unit/acceptance tests.
2. Not good for components that depends from Illuminate\Http\Request (i.e. if you will use ReactPHP adapter for Laravel/Lumen).

Comment: Whenever possible, you shouldn't directly access $_GET or $_POST fields, as they might contain unescaped data.