# How to get All input of POST in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 and trying to get all input of POST variable in controller like this-

```
public function add_question()
{
    return Request::all();
}
```

So, I am getting this errors-

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::all() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Comment: The code above is fine. All that is needed is the line `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;` at the top of the file. For just the post data, `Request::post()` could be used instead.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try this :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
public function add_question(Request $request)
{
    return $request->all();
}
```

Comment: Wrong! It will return also GET variables.

Comment: @barbushin, If all answers here are wrong, provide CORRECT answer here.

Comment: @ShaunakShukla I have provided the correct answer that only shows POST data (although your solution solves the main error the OP was having)

Comment: @Shaunak Shukla I don't understand. You said to provide the correct answer in your comment to barbushin. So I did.

Comment: This didn't work for me, Laravel version 5.2.45

Answer (score 92):

There seems to be a major mistake in almost all the current answers in that they show **BOTH** GET and POST data. Not **ONLY** POST data.

The issue with your code as the accepted answer mentioned is that you did not import the facade. This can imported by adding the following at the top:

```
use Request;

public function add_question(Request $request)
{
    return Request::post();
}
```

You can also use the global request method like so (mentioned by @Canaan Etai), with no import required:

```
request()->post();
```

However, a better approach to importing `Request` in a controller method is by dependency injection as mentioned in @shuvrow answer:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function add_question(Request $request)
{
    return $request->post();
}
```

More information about DI can be found here:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers

In either case, you should use:

```
// Show only POST data
$request->post(); // DI
request()->post(); // global method
Request::post(); // facade

// Show only GET data
$request->query(); // DI
request()->query(); // global method
Request::query(); // facade

// Show all data (i.e. both GET and POST data)
$request->all(); // DI
request()->all(); // global method
Request::all(); // facade
```

Comment: Great answer with solid information and great explanations. Thank you, you just saved me from another hour of googling.

Comment: nice explanation with doc references.

Comment: Return error **Method post does not exist**. Also i can't find `post()` in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests)

Comment: I should probably try and get the docs updated. But here it is in the API docs: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.html#method_post .

Comment: Method post is only available in Laravel >= 5.5, for 5.4 and below try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46355735/2836233)

Answer (score 17):

For those who came here looking for "how to get All input of POST" only

## TLDR;

**Laravel >= 5.5**

```
$request->post() 
// or 
$request->post('my_param')
```

**Older Versions**

```
$request->request->all(); //Get all post requests
$request->request->get('my_param'); //Get a post parameter
```

## Explanation

class `Illuminate\Http\Request` extends from `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` which has two class variables that store request parameters.

`public $query` - for GET parameters

`public $request` - for POST parameters

```
$request->request->all(); //Get all post requests
$request->request->get('my_param'); //Get a post parameter
```

`$request->post()` for versions 5.5 and above internally calls `$request->request->all()` or `$request->request->get('my_param')` respectively.

Source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27367330/2836233)

Comment: I think my solution to this issue is better. Just do `$request->post()`

Comment: `$request->post()` is only available in Laravel >= 5.5

Answer (score 6):

You should use the facade rather than `Illuminate\Http\Request`. Import it at the top:

```
use Request;
```

And make sure it doesn't conflict with the other class.

Edit: This answer was written a few years ago. I now favour the approach suggested by shuvrow below.

Comment: Wrong! It will return also GET variables.

Comment: @barbushin The question was how to retrieve the POST variables. I never said it doesn't also retrieve GET variables. Kindly read before commenting, and don't be an ass.

Comment: If it will be GET request, then `return Request::all();` will return GET variables.

Comment: @barbushin I have provided an answer that only gives POST data. Not both GET and POST data,

Answer (score 4):

You can get all post data into this function :-

```
$postData = $request->post();
```

and if you want specific filed then use it :-

```
$request->post('current-password');
```

Answer (score 1):

its better to use the Dependency than to attache it to the class.

```
public function add_question(Request $request)
{
    return Request::all();
}
```

or if you prefer using input variable use

```
public function add_question(Request $input)
{
    return $input::all();
}
```

you can now use the global request method provided by laravel

```
request()
```

for example to get the first_name of a form input.

```
request()->first_name
// or
request('first_name')
```

Comment: Hello DejavuGuy, kindly check the date that this answer was provided

Answer (score 1):

You can use it

```
$params = request()->all();
```

without

`import Illuminate\Http\Request`   OR

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request` OR other.

Answer (score 0):

It should be at least this:

```
public function login(Request $loginCredentials){
     $data = $loginCredentials->all();
     return $data['username'];
}
```