# Laravel 5 Collecting Post Data

Tags: laravel-5

I am having an issue with working with post data.

For example, if i have a simple little form :

```
<form action='/leads/getpost' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='Domain'>
<input type='submit' name='submit'>
```

AND then collect the data and try echo it out :

```
public function getPost()
    {
        $formData = Request::all() ;
        var_dump($formData);

        //
    }
```

I get an error : MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

If i do the same thing using GET it works fine.

I tried to edit the VerifyCsrfToken and added :

```
protected $except = [ 'leads/getpost'
        //
    ];
```

Still not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718870/how-to-get-all-input-of-post-in-laravel-5

Comment: @LeszekRepie , i tried those examples , still not working

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/methodnotallowedhttpexception-in-routecollectionphp-line-218 ?

Comment: The URL you're `POST`ing to isn't configured in your `routes.php` file. You need `Route::post("url", "Controller@getPost");` or something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

**Route:**

```
Route::post('leads/getpost', 'nameofController@getPost');
```

**Controller:**

```
use Request;

public function getPost()
    {
        $formData = Request::all();
        var_dump($formData); // or you could return it to the view

    }
```