# I'm doing everything right but still getting error

Tags: laravel, api

Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CurriculumController::show()

```
public function show($request)
    {
        $id = $request->id;
        return Curriculum::find($id);
    }


Route::post('/curriculum', [CurriculumController::class, 'show']);
```

Comment: what is route? Tell about route also

Comment: Route::post('/curriculum', [CurriculumController::class, 'show']);

this is the route

Comment: Any reason why your "show" route uses `POST` and not `GET`? And no `id` in your route? How do you determine which data to show?

Comment: My boss has told me to send data in the body, and then destructure id from it.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why not compare that action to others that work to spot the difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get All input of POST in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718870/how-to-get-all-input-of-post-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing Class `Request`

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 public function show(Request $request)
```