# Laravel 5.3 - POST is polluted with GET values

Tags: php, post, laravel-5.3

back in the (real) days, we used to use `$_GET`, `$_POST`! and now we got Laravel's `\Request::input()`. Consequently here is whats happening:

```
if(\Request::isMethod('post'))
{
    $POST = \Request::input();
}
```

if I have the a variable in $_GET, the value gets in the POST as well.

For example:

`&x=1` //i.e. in the query string

`$_POST['x'] = null;` //as it was not posted with the form, but it could be as there is a field with same name

`$POST['x'] = 1;` //as its in the GET, but should be null as its not in the $_POST!

Any solution to get POSTed vars only? Or shall I just use $_POST?

Thanks

Comment: Might want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/27367330/583608

Comment: Thanks @ToothlessRebel that helped. Now im using `\Request::instance()->request` instead of `\Request::input()`

Comment: in fact, `\Request::instance()->request->all()` to get array

Comment: It's php after all, so you can always use $_POST if don't want to call those weird functions :D

Comment: its funny, if you look into `Illuminate\Http\Request` class, you can see the method `getInputSource()` which does the exact same thing, but its `protected`. On top of that, its pulled into the public method `input()` to get the input as both arrays of get and post ($input = `$this->getInputSource()->all() + $this->query->all()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only way to get this from the `Request` instance is to access either the `query` (GET) or `request` (POST) property. These are both `ParameterBag` instances, so you'll probably use the `->get()` method of them to access the parameter you want.